# Persist Dask array compressed in memory

Tags: python, numpy, compression, dask

Suppose I have a class that stores a numpy array in a compressed way, but also supports indexing:

```
class Compressed:
    def __init__(self, numpy_array):
        "... store numpy_array in a compressed way ..."
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return "... the equivalent of numpy_array[index] ..."
```

Is there a reasonable (non-hacky) way to get this to work nicely with persistence? I would like to be able to define a large (but rather compressible) array x, and then get the equivalent of x.persist() but where the in-memory data is all wrapped inside Compressed instances. Bonus if it can work with `dask.persist()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could map your `Compressed` class on the blocks of your dask.array, persist that, and then follow up with a call to `np.asarray`.  Your data will be persisted in compressed form.  This is slightly illegal because most numpy operations won't work on these blocks.  However if you follow up with lazy calls to `np.asarray` then everything should be safe.

#### Example

In the example below we do this with the `bcolz.carray` class, which implements a compressed array.

```
import bcolz
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

x = da.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 1000, 1000), chunks=(100, 100, 100))

x = x.map_blocks(bcolz.carray).persist().map_blocks(np.asarray)  # <<--- main point

import psutil; 

>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / x.nbytes  # compression ratio
0.173897216

>>> x.sum().compute()  # things still work
49499671807
```

#### Slicing

However this does call `np.asarray` on each block before access, which may not be maximally efficient if your compression scheme supports random access.  If this is critical to you let me know and I'll see if I can find a workaround.

#### Dask stores data compressed on disk

Also, it's worth pointing out that if you are using the distributed scheduler and if you have local disk to each node then Dask will dump excess data to disk in a compressed format.  This is obviously slower than reading from in-memory compressed data, but still may be useful.